# How to use pipe to filter items listed inside third party component

Tags: angular

I am using a third party tree view control `angular2-tree-component` inside my angular 2 component. I am using it as given below:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>
```

Here `nodes` is an array of objects of `TrItem` class which looks like:

```
export class TrItem{
    itemId: number,
    name: string,
    itemDesc: string,
    blahBlah: string
}
```

`name` property is used to display the node in tree.

I want to use an **input text** element which would filter the nodes displayed inside `tree-root` component as we type in to the input as given below:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "nodeFilter"/>
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

create new pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByName'
})

export class FilterByNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], name:string): any[] {  
    let result: any = [];  
    if (value && name) {  
      value.forEach((item) => {  
        if(item.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()) {  
          result.push(item);  
        }  
      });  
    }  
    else if(value) {  
      result = value;  
    }  

    return result;  
  }  
}
```

include it in you application module:

```
import { FilterByNamePipe } from "PATH_TO_YOUR_PIPE_CLASS_FILE";
```

don't forget about the `declarations` list of the `@NgModule(...)`:

```
declarations: [
  //...
  FilterByNamePipe,
  //...
]
```

use it in your html:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes | filterByName : nodeFilter"></tree-root>
```

this pipe will check strictly the items with the exact value of their `name` property. if you want to filter the items which **contains** the filtered value **within** their names then you have to change this condition:

```
item.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
```

with something else, depends on your requirements... maybe [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: within the pipe you could use your `TrItem` type instead of `any` type